# CodeIgniter Reading Model with NuSoap

Tags: php, codeigniter, soap, nusoap

May I know if my current method of returning data from a model is incorrect? I've been trying out Nusoap but I am quite confused. It keeps saying 'You must provide an array for operation outputs'. I hope someone can take a look at this for me.

My Model

```
public function get_all(){
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('countries');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        if($query->num_rows()>0){
            foreach($query->result()as $row){
                $countries[] = $row;
            }
            return $countries;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

My Controller that handles the request

```
<?php
class GetCountries extends CI_Controller{
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('CountriesModel');
        require_once APPPATH.'libraries/nusoap/nusoap.php';
        $this->nusoap_server = new soap_server();
        $this->nusoap_server->configureWSDL(' Get Countries','urn:DMS_Transactions');
        $this->nusoap_server->wsdl->addComplexType(
            'Countries',
            'complexType',
            'struct',
            'all',
            '',
            array(
                'id'=>array('name'=>'id','type'=>'xsd:int'),
                'country_code'=>array('name'=>'country_code','type'=>'xsd:string'),
                'country'=>array('name'=>'country','type'=>'xsd:string')
            )
        );
        $this->nusoap_server->register('getCountries',
                array('Countries'=>'tns:Countries'),
                'urn:DMS_Transactions',
                'urn:DMS_Transactions#getCountries',
                'rpc',
                'encoded',
                'Get All Countries'
                );
    }

    public function index(){
        function getCountries(){

            $res = array(
                'countries'=>$this->CountriesModel->get_all()
            );
            return json_encode($res);
        }
        $this->nusoap_server->service(file_get_contents("php://input"));  
    }
}
```

Comment: In `register()` method you are providing `$in` array but you also need to provide `$out` array. Check some examples [here](http://www.discorganized.com/php/a-complete-nusoap-and-flex-example-part-1-the-nusoap-server/). Disclaimer: I didn't use nusoap so far, but checking library code, that [error message](https://github.com/econea/nusoap/blob/master/src/nusoap.php#L4540) is returned when `$out` array doesn't exist.

Comment: What happens if I do not want to set an input?

Comment: I am not sure. Just reading in code that those are values must be set. Otherwise method stops execution. That is how `register()` method works. It is all I can tell. I hope it will get you somewhere near solution.